# A link is part of an image. Problems on resizing

Tags: html, css

There's only one background image, and link images are part of the image. I need to attach `<a href="#" ..` to this background image.

The problem:

Since these images are part of one the image, it becomes very hard to make it responsive.
Currently I have a div which contains `a` tag with a needed `href` attribute.

CSS:

```
#link_div {
 height: 14%;
 left: 29%;
 top: 44%;
 width: 6%;
}
```

[image]

If I resize a window, then I need to `height`, `left`, `top`, `width` to be changed dynamically according to a new window size. Is it possible to solve with CSS?

Comment: I'm confused by your question. It sounds from the question that you just want to make the image a link, but I don't think that is your goal. Are you trying to make multiple links the same size as the circles?

Comment: Check your background image width (assuming the image is at max 100% of the container of the links) and check the distances of the link positions in the image -> convert pixels to %. For example: % of image width from left edge to Link 1 left edge, % from Link 1 left edge to Link 1 right edge. These give you the % CSS `left` and `width` of Link 1 `<a>`

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. if you have an absolute link your css code will be like this:

```
a {
    display:block;
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:9;
    left:calc(50% - 50px);
    left:-ms-calc(50% - 50px);
    left:-moz-calc(50% - 50px);
    top:calc(50% - 50px);
    top:-ms-calc(50% - 25px);
    top:-moz-calc(50% - 25px);
}
```

With this css your a tg always be centered. if you want something else you change css parameter. sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 1):

This is an option you can do, `SVG` images can help a lot. (Scalable Vector Graphic)

This will let the circle be as responsive as you like, has decent browser support IE9+, and is a small file size.

The css to make it fluid:

```
div.circ-wrap {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

div.circ-wrap a {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

div.circ-wrap img {
    width: 100%;
}

div.circ-wrap span {
    position: absolute;
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -30px;
    margin-top: -30px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Finally, a fiddle: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YYD3W/)

Also, a fiddle of a centered circle: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YYD3W/1/)